# How to do XML File Changes in InstallShield LE

Tags: installshield-le

I'm using InstallShield Limited Edition on VS2015.

I found several articles talking about an XML File Changes view, like [this article](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield21helplib/helplibrary/XML-Overview.htm), for instance.
However, I can't locate the view in LE. It might be due to the articles being a bit old and for a different version, or it might be that LE doesn't have this feature. I haven't found an article with the specific differences in features between the various versions of InstallShield, so my question is, can we do XML File Changes in LE? If yes, which view should I use to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed InstallShield Express Edition, and while navigating the Help, I found the article entitled **Upgrading to the Premier or Professional Editions of InstallShield**. In it, you'll find the following:

> **Features that Are in Only the Premier and Professional Editions**
>
> (...)
>
> Ability to modify text files or XML files—Use the Text File Changes view or the XML File Changes view to configure files that you want to modify on the target system at run time.

So this answers my question. Hope it helps someone else out there.